# I want to display User videos and Other's videos separately. I am not getting output from the following code, Is my approach correct?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

My view goes something like this

```
class Test(ListView):
    model = VideoUpload
    template_name = 'videoTube/videoTube.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["my_video_list"] = VideoUpload.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        context["other_video_list"] = VideoUpload.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user)
        print(context)
        return context
```

Template code

```
{% for vid in my_video_list %}
  {% if forloop.counter < 5 %}
    {{ vid.video }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for vid in other_video_list %}
  {% if forloop.counter < 5 %}
    {{ vid.video }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am not getting anything in the output. I am expecting my_video_list and other_video_list should be displayed separately

Comment: do you mean u are not getting any output for that print statement also?

Comment: No, not getting for that print also

Comment: Could you also update your models.py?

Comment: 1. are you sure that you have any objects in `VideoUpload` model? 2. if you prepare all your video lists in `get_context`, you probably don't need to inherit from `ListView`. Because in `ListView` you will get third video list (`object_list`) ini `get_query` method.